# How to be informed that some database information has been changed in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mariadb, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm working on a code wrote in Python 2.7 that connects to a MariaDB database to read data.
This database receives data from different external resources. My code only read it.
My service read the data once at the beginning and keep everything in memory to avoid I/O.

I would like to know if there is someway to create some 'function callback' in my code to receive some kind of alert of new update/insert, so I can reload my memory data from the database every time that any external resource change or save new data.

I have thought of creating a sql trigger to a new table to insert some "flag" there and put my service to check that new table periodically if the flag is present.
If so, reload the data and delete the flag.
But it sounds like a wrong workaround...

I'm using:

- Python 2.7
- MariaDB  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.24-MariaDB
- lib mysql-connector 2.1.6

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should be aware that Python 2.7 has been sunsetted for years: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Comment: Yes, I know.. The upgrade to 3.x is gonna be the first thing to do after I finish the critical issues opened for this product. Thanks

Comment: And I made some edits to your tags and question because at this point, MariaDB is not MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed enough by now that you should think of MariaDB as a completely different product. You can't assume that solutions for one work for the other.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution for MariaDB is streaming with the CDC API: https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-stream-change-data-through-mariadb-maxscale-using-cdc-api/

The plan you have now, with using a flag table, means your client has to poll the flag table for presence of the flag. You have to run a query against that table at intervals, and keep doing it 24/7. Depending on how quickly your client needs to be notified of a change, you might need to run this type of polling query very frequently, which puts a burden on the MariaDB server just to respond to the polling queries, even when there is no change to report.

The CDC solution is better because the client can just request to be notified the next time a change occurs, then the client waits. It does not put extra load on the MariaDB server, any more than if you had simply added a replica server.